# How can I enable the port forwarding on the Anker N600 Wireless-N Dual Band (2.4GHz & 5GHz) router?

Tags: port-forwarding

How can I enable [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on the Anker N600 Wireless-N Dual Band (2.4GHz & 5GHz) router?

I couldn't find the option in the admin panel. I wonder whether I missed it or it doesn't exist.

---

Link to Dual Band (2.4G&5G) Wireless-N Router 600Mbps instruction manual: https://d2211byn0pk9fi.cloudfront.net/spree/products/accessoies/345/39E6A9172FC706F_66ANDBWRN6-WA_manuals.zip (link found on https://www.anker.com/download?keyword=Dual+Band+%282.4G%265G%29+Wireless-N+Router+600Mbps)

Example of port forwarding: I have a computer connected to the  Anker N600. The computer has a FTP server, which uses the port 21. The  Anker N600 is connected to the Internet. I would like to be able to access the FTP server from some computer located outside the Anker N600 network.

Comment: User manual, page 86.

Comment: @AFH Are you referring to http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WNDR3400V2/WNDR3400v2_UM_23JAN2013.pdf? If so, you're talking about netgear N600, not Anker N600.

Comment: @Downvoter please explain.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt  have you tried calling them? https://www.anker.com/contact and do you have a link to the manual?

Comment: @barlop Good point, I have just sent an email to them. I have added a link to the instruction manual in the question.

Comment: @ITSnuggles Thanks, my router is a anker, not NetGear.

Comment: @ITSnuggles Example of port forwarding: I have a computer connected to the  Anker N600. The computer has a FTP server, which uses the port 21. The  Anker N600 is connected to the Internet. I would like to be able to access the FTP server from some computer located outside the Anker N600 network.

Comment: @ITSnuggles So far I'm quite pessimistic as to whether Anker N600 allows port forwarding. The only related option I have found is adding a DMZ host, which is pretty much the same as doing port forward for all ports to a given computer in the Anker N600 network.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt If you have to explain to somebody what port forwarding on a router is do you seriously think they will be able to help you. What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt  look at page 10 of the manual  https://i.imgur.com/1zgl6C6.png or any scan of the manual for the word 'port'.

Comment: @ITSnuggles  Please stop deleting your comments trying to hide all your mistakes, it makes what is being said difficult to follow because you keep removing context. Port forwarding is NAPT which is a form of NAT.

Comment: @ITSnuggles  I just said look at page 10 of the manual.. Reason is that it may help. And is worth looking at and Trying out.  I did not say that it is or is not for port forwarding, i'm not presuming one way or the other. We won't know until it is tried. Maybe the chances are 50/50. But it's worth him trying it.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - I very much apologise. I am very busy on the run-up to Christmas and I rushed a reply based on Google's first link. When looking for a manual more thoroughly I found that links pointed to a Tenda manual, and some sources indicate that the Anker is a re-badging of this model. If this is so, then the manual section you need is "Virtual Server", which is an alternative term for more or less the same thing.

Comment: @ITSnuggles I do: please see the answer I just added (I was waiting to try it before posting it; I'm currently in a different location and do not have access to the N600). Looks like AFH was correct!

Answer (score 2):

From Anker's customer support:

> You will find the port forwarding in configuration as: Advanced--Virtual--Add:

[image]

I haven't tried it yet.